# Graph is hamiltonian iff $n$-closure is $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I have seen this statement and was wondering how one might show that if a graph (with $|V(G)| = n$ vertices) is hamiltonian, that then it's $n$-closure is the $K_n$ (note that this is refering to simple graphs with $n \geq 3$)

The $n$-closure of $G$ is refering to the longest possible sequence (or rather the last element of the sequence) of graphs $G_0, G_1, \ldots, G_h$ $(G_0 := G)$ such that from $G_i$ to $G_{i+1}$ for $x,y \in V(G_i)$ non-adjacent with $d_{G_i}(x) + d_{G_{i}} (y) \geq n$ the edge $xy$ was added (it can be shown that this closure is well defined and unique).

The other implication follows with Ore's lemma as far as I know.

One could use Ore's lemma for the other direction aswell however I don't see why $d(x)+ d(y) \geq n$ should hold for every $x,y \in V(G)$. Especially since it is sufficient for $d(x) + d(y) \geq n-4$ and $G$ to be $1$-tough for $G$ to be hamiltonian.

Comment: Can the transitive closure of a connected graph on $n$ vertices be different from $K_n$? 
 What I mean is that if the transitive closure of a graph on $n$ vertices is $K_n$, then this graph is connected and not necessarily Hamiltonian.

Comment: @kabenyuk I don't seem to understand what you are saying. For example $C_n$ with $n \geq 5$ would obviously have a hamiltonian circle, however, $d(x) + d(y) = 4$ for all $x,y \in V(C_n)$ as such $C_n = cl_n (C_n)$ where $cl_n(G)$ describes the transitive closure of $G$ and obsiously $C_n \not \cong K_n$. For your last sentence I would refer you to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129053/how-to-prove-a-simple-graph-is-hamiltonian-if-and-only-if-its-closure-is-hamilto) post

Comment: Clarify your question, because the term 'transitive closure' is used in graph theory in a completely different sense, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory.

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes, I have added the definition I am refering to

Comment: [Bondy and Chvatal call it](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X76900789) *$k$-closure*, nothing about transitiveness

Comment: @Smylic Yes. Thank you. That is the same definition. That seems to be an issue with the translation from german where it is called transitive closure in my script about graph theory. The definition is the same nonetheless.

Comment: @RaoulLuqué
Now that we've sorted out the definitions let's get back to your question. I still don't understand it. On the one hand, you write that you have seen somewhere a statement that if a graph is of order $n$ Hamiltonian, then its $n$-closure is $K_n$.
On the other hand in your comment you write that $n$-closure of $C_n$ is $C_n$. What is the meaning of this?

Comment: @kabenyuk Actually that is a very valid argument. I am afraid I was a bit blind. I have seen that statement, however must have misread it as an implication in both instead of only one direction. Thank you for the comments and help, I will answer my own question with my own counterexample then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given by myself as an counterexample and identified by kabenyuk as such. The Graph $C_n$ (Cirlce with $n$ nodes) is a counter example to the claim:
$G$ is hamiltonian $\implies$ $cl_n (G) \cong K_n$,
since $cl_n (C_n) = C_n \not \cong K_n$.

As such the statement is wrong